# ios filter to remove pixelation

Tags: ios

I have an image with resolution 200 * 300. I scale the image to 600*900 using core graphics,as a result of which image starts pixelating. Is there any filter in ios or any other technique by which I can reduce the pixelation after I scale the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a good interpolator when resizing. That should be all that's needed.

> I scale the image to 600*900 using core graphics…

If you scale using `CGContextDrawImage`, then you probably just need to add `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(gtx, kCGInterpolationHigh);` before calling `CGContextDrawImage`. You may also want to tweak the context's anti-aliasing parameters.

Comment: + (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    [self beginImageContextWithSize:newSize];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self endImageContext];
    return newImage;
}

Comment: I update my code by adding couple of lines. Is it correct ?                         [self beginImageContextWithSize:newSize];
    CGContextRef cgf=    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(cgf, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self endImageContext];
    CFRelease(cgf);
    return newImage;

Comment: @Deep2012 that looks right - although you should not release `cgf`, which was accessed via an interface which returns by the "Get Rule".

Comment: Wouldn't there be memory leak if I don't release cgf ?

Comment: @Deep2012 no. it follows the "Get Rule", rather than the "Create" or "Copy" rule.